Tailwind: Why are all grid columns the same height?
I have a grid, with 4 columns, but its only a grid on lg screens.
I'm trying to understand why each column has a fixed height of the longest column?
Is there a way for other columns not to be stretched unnecessarily just because others are longer?
Here is a demo:
<div class="flex">
  <div class="w-full space-y-4 p-3">
    <div class="mb-4 space-y-4 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-4 lg:gap-x-4 lg:gap-y-4 lg:space-y-0">
      <div class="bg-red-200">
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-green-200">
        <p class="font-bold">dskdsksdak</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-blue-200">
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


What is the final effect you are trying to achieve?

@KarsonJo So I just want the columns to be as high as each inner content needs them to be, not enforced by the longest column.

On top of that, do you want a multi-row layout? If so, I think you need a masonry layout.

One way is to simply wrap each colored div in another div. The grid will enforce the height of its directly descending divs, but not their children.


<div class="flex">
  <div class="w-full space-y-4 p-3">
    <div class="mb-4 space-y-4 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-4 lg:gap-x-4 lg:gap-y-4 lg:space-y-0">
      <div>
        <div class="bg-red-200">
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="bg-green-200">
          <p class="font-bold">dskdsksdak</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="bg-blue-200">
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
          <p>skksdkaskaksaksadksakas</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



But if this is the effect you're looking for, a flexbox solution might be simpler than a grid.
